# Angular-datatables error loading data

Tags: angular, angular-datatables

I'm new in this community and need some help.

I'm loading some data in my website (data loaded from Spring Boot), but when i load this data in my datatable, this show it but haven't got the datatable information loaded.

Probably the problem is because datatable was generated before server call, and when I receive the data this show in my datatable.

Visual image problem:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4304.png)

And my Angular 4 code:

```
  export class ReportsComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  reports: Report[];
  dtTrigger: Subject<Report> = new Subject();

  dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {
    language: {
        search: "_INPUT_",
        searchPlaceholder: "Buscar informe...",
        info: "Mostrando del _START_ al _END_ en un total de _TOTAL_ informes"
      },
    dom: '<"#customTable"<"top"fi>rt<"bottom"p>>'
  };

  constructor(private reportsService: ReportsService, private reportsEventService: ReportsEventsService, private modalService: NgbModal) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.reportsEventService.onReportsChanged.subscribe(reports => { 
      this.reports = reports;
    });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.dtTrigger.next();
  }

  ...
```

And html code:

```
<table id="informesTable" datatable class="table row-border" [dtOptions]="dtOptions">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>CIP</th>
      <th>Género</th>
      <th>Fecha de nacimiento</th>
      <th>Último seguimiento</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let report of reports">
            <td>{{report.id}}</td>
            <td>{{report.patient.cip}}</td>
            <td>{{report.patient.gender}}</td>
            <td>{{report.patient.birthdate | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</td>
            <td>{{report.patient.lastFollow | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm'}}</td>
            <td class="float-right">
                <div class="dropdown" dropdown [dropdownToggle]="false">
                    <a dropdown-open>
                        <span>
                            <i class="fas fa-cog"></i>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                    <div class="pane-dropdown-menu">
                        <span>
                            <ul class="pane-dropdown-list">
                                <li><a routerLink="/app/reports/{{report.id}}/0">Edit</a></li>
                                <li><a style="color: red!important" (click)="openModal(report)">DELETE</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Add a `debugger` statement after you assign this.reports = reports in the response handler and make sure the data appears correct there... also check the network panel to see if the appropriate request and response shows there.  Nothing obviously wrong in your use of ngFor it will typically handle changes to the data that happen async for you.

Comment: Give a try to `<ng-container *ngIf="response"><table.......//rest of your html code   <ng-container>`